# Need to change the JS order change in AEM clientlibs

Tags: javascript, aem, min.js

I have a set of script tag loading on the body level of the AEM instance since there is a cache issue because of the ordering in clientlibs which is getting loaded. I want to change the order and have control of arranging the script tag.

Attaching a screenshot for reference.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts might be loading from the head.html file. Could you please check the file and rearrange the client library's order? It should solve your problem.